# HTTPS connection over any SSL or TLS versions

Tags: ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to implement SSL based HTTPS connention to other servers.

I need to providin all protocols (`TLSv1.0`, `TLSv1.1`, `TLSv1.2`, `TLSv1.3`) and whichever is available or enabled it should be able to negotiate that version  itself.

Currently, it is something like this :

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, /*some certs*/, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        String webServicePath =" https://google.com"  //suppose

        URL url = new URL(webServicePath); 

        HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        httpsCon.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        httpsCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpsCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        httpsCon.setUseCaches(false);
        httpsCon.setDoInput(true);
        httpsCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpsCon.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        }); 
        httpsCon.connect();
```

I want something like :  **SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2");** but i am not sure if this method takes multiple arguments.

I found solutions : **Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1” when starting the Java VM, or in code, the equivalent system property directive is “System.setProperty(“https.protocols”, “TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1”)”.**

I want to do it programmatically in my code  but I have no idea how.

I read that the client and server negotiate via HELLO message till they agree upon a supported version of the protocol by the duo. To achieve this negotiation, do I have to implement it in source code?

Comment: "I am trying to implement SSL based HTTPS". First advice: stop saying SSL. This is has been supersed by TLS created almost 20 years ago now.

Comment: "whichever is available or enabled it should be able to negotiate that version itself" have a long read of RFC8446 about TLS1.3 that has extensive sections on how to interoperate with a 1.3-server and older clients or the opposite. There are many fine details to implement properly. "I read that the client and server negotiate via HELLO message till they agree upon a supported version of the protocol by the duo." this is called `ServerHello` and `ClientHello` in the TLS handshake. All of this should be abstracted away by the TLS library you use, start by reading its documentation.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the response. Actually my code is hitting a web service and don't know why i am getting Handshake failure Exception  on _httpsCon.connect();_ - **java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure** . The same code is working fine on PROD. First i thought its version compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that. But you need to write some extra code.

- Create a custom socket factory

  ```
  public class CustomCipherFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
     @Override
   public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3)
       throws IOException {

      Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
      SSLParameters p = ((SSLSocket)socket).getSSLParameters();
      p.setProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.3","TLSv1.2" });
     ((SSLSocket)socket).setSSLParameters(p);
     return socket;
   }
  }
  ```
- Set that socket factory to httpsUrlConnection (it's a static method, so the impact is global unless you unset it).

  ```
  SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomCipherFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sf);
  ```